Animate procedural cracking
I created procedural crack on a plane using this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYEaJxw4pSo
So far so good, but at the very end of the video, the guy animates the crack forming on its length and he doesn't explain how he does it. I have tried using mapping+Gradient Texture+Color Ramp at various places in my node tree but when it does affect the crack, it only changes the pattern or makes it go up and down my plane.
Any ideas on what nodes I need to add to my setup to affect the length of the crack?
PROJECT FILE : 



Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

@Jakemoyo here is my project file : https://blend-exchange.com/b/5jgYKVB1/
